# How to test multiple file upload using Cucumber/Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I could test upload of one file

```
attach_file 'photo', File.join(Rails.root, 'public', 'uploads', 'test.png')
```

But what if I have a file field with `multiple` atribute? How can I test multiple files upload using Cucumber/Capybara?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is currently not possible with Capybara:

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/37

Comment: This answer was correct at the time, but I think @user2391218 has the new correct answer.

Answer (score 25):

HTML:

```
<input id="fileupload" class="photo-uploader" type="file" multiple="" name="images">
```

Capybara:

```rb
page.attach_file "images", ['path to file1.jpg', 'path to file2.jpg', 'path to file3.jpg']
```

1. Look for the `name` attribute of the `<input>` with `type="file"` and add it as the first parameter.
2. Add the path to the files [as the second parameter](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#attach_file-instance_method). Refer to the statement given above. Do not use relative paths for uploading the file.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Simple and it works.